# drag and drop - image returns to original location

Tags: android, button, drag-and-drop, android-linearlayout

I use Android `Drag and Drop` to `drag` my image around the screen. When I `drop`, the image returns to its original location. But I want the image to stay in the location it was dropped in.

My attempt: I saved the X and Y positions of the image at `ACTION_DROP`, then tried to set the new `view` position with those same X and Y coordinates.

Can someone please help?

And please let me know if I need to provide more code.

Code:

```
class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                if(v==findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_button))
                    findViewById(R.id.removeText).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                if(v==findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_button))
                    findViewById(R.id.removeText).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                if(v==findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_image)) {
                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    float posx = view.getX();
                    float posy = view.getY();
                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                    owner.removeView(view);
                    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                    container.addView(view);
                    view.setX(posx);
                    view.setY(posy);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: try get the x,y values from the event variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using your x y positions again. Try by commenting this two lines

```
   // view.setX(posx);
// view.setY(posy);
```

Comment: SO provides comment option, use it

Comment: What is SO? please explain